# Unable to understand the logic behind swapping two variables without using a third one. How exactly do we extract original values of variables?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("a = "))
b = int(input("b = "))
print("values before swapping : ",a,b)
a = a+b
b = a-b
a = a-b
print("values after swapping : ",a,b)
```

Comment: Format your question... This is hard to make sense of and the code is all over the place (Use ```)

Comment: This isn't a programming question, just basic maths. Note in Python you can do `a, b = b, a` and skip the maths (it works with values that aren't numbers, too).

Comment: Thanks for correctly modifying the code. This is my first post on the community and i am really looking forward to be a regular here from now on ^^ . Also I didn't know that we could directly swap and skip all the math in python, that's awesome.

Comment: I provided an answer, which hopefully clarifies the question too. Please mark as accepted if this is what you meant in the question.

Comment: @D.L yep thanks your answer clarified it, but hey can you just explain how we can swap by storing the sum a+b ? i do realize we can swap easily in python but wanted to know the logic behind the alternate method which stores the sum in first variable and then swaps

Comment: You wouldn't store the sum (even in other languages that dont offer a,b switch). What one would do is assign a third variable and proceed with the switching (but you do not wish to do this in the question). I am not even sure that this is mathematically possible for all a,b (and have never seen it).

Comment: @D.L The idea is to store sum in one of the two numbers, then the numbers are swapped using the sum and subtraction from the sum. 
#original values of a and b are 5 and 10
'a = 5 + 10  # a = a+b   Now a = 15'
'b = 15 - 10 # b = a-b   Now b = 5'
'a = 15 - 5  # a = a-b   Now a = 10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by swapping variables you mean `a = 5` and `b = 10` and how can we swap them such that `a = 10` and `b = 5` then we can do this very easily in python using the `comma` operator (without having to use a third variable).

Here is the code (example):

```
a = 10
b = 5
print(f'the original a,b pair: ({a}, {b})')

# now swap a and b
a, b = b, a

print(f'the swapped a,b pair: ({a}, {b})')
```

And here is the result:

```
the original a,b pair: (10, 5)
the swapped a,b pair: (5, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain:

```
a = 5 #a = int(input("a = "))
b = 10 #b = int(input("b = "))

a = 5 + 10  # a = a+b   Now a = 15
b = 15 - 10 # b = a-b   Now b = 5
a = 15 - 5  # a = a-b   Now a = 10
```

Thats how it works.

Comment: ...that doesn't really _explain_ anything. You've just provided an example.